# Storing functions in a variable

Tags: php

I don't understand how this thing works but I need to create a new function and store it in a variable. Then, by using `array_filter`, remove all dogs that are under certain age. Here is what I created so far:

```
$animals = [
  [ 'name' => 'Waffles', 'type' => 'dog', 'age'  => 12],
  [ 'name' => 'Fluffy',  'type' => 'cat', 'age'  => 14],
  [ 'name' => 'Spelunky', 'type' => 'dog', 'age'  => 4],
  [ 'name' => 'Hank'      , 'type' => 'dog', 'age'  => 11],
];


$youngDogs = function ($animals, $filter){    
    array_filter(
        $animals, 
        function($animals, $age = 5){
            $arr = [];
            if($animals['type'] == 'dog' && $animals['age'] < $age)
            {
                $arr = [
                    'name' => $animals['name'],
                    'type' => $animals['type'],
                    'age' => $animals['age'],
                ];
            }
            return $arr;
        }
    );
};


var_dump($youngDogs($animals, 5));
```

My idea is to create a new array and store the dogs that match the criteria and return it, however everything is a mess and the function is returning NULL and I don't know what is happening anymore. Could anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need `use($age)` as `array_filter` passes only one argument to the callback
- You need to `return` the result of `array_filter` from your function
- `array_filter` expects `true` or `false` to be returned from the callback

---

```
$youngDogs = function ($animals, $age){    
                return array_filter($animals, 
                    function($animal) use($age){
                        if($animal['type'] == 'dog' && $animal['age'] < $age) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                );
             };
```

Comment: Thank you! I never would have figured out how to use `$age`!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define a new function, just create an anonymous function inside of `array_filter` like this:

```
$animals = [
    ['name' => 'Waffles', 'type' => 'dog', 'age' => 12],
    ['name' => 'Fluffy', 'type' => 'cat', 'age' => 14],
    ['name' => 'Spelunky', 'type' => 'dog', 'age' => 4],
    ['name' => 'Hank', 'type' => 'dog', 'age' => 11],
];

$animals = array_filter($animals, function ($animal) {
    return ($animal['type'] != 'dog' || $animal['age'] >= 5); // Keep if not a dog, or is a dog, and is over 5.
});

var_dump($animals);
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/868706)

Or, if you really need the function as a variable, try this:

```
$youngDogs = function ($animal) {
    return ($animal['type'] != 'dog' || $animal['age'] >= 5); // Keep if not a dog, or is a dog, and is over 5.
};

$animals = array_filter($animals, $youngDogs);
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/868705)

Answer (score 0):

```
$animals = [
  [ 'name' => 'Waffles', 'type' => 'dog', 'age'  => 12],
  [ 'name' => 'Fluffy',  'type' => 'cat', 'age'  => 14],
  [ 'name' => 'Spelunky', 'type' => 'dog', 'age'  => 4],
  [ 'name' => 'Hank'      , 'type' => 'dog', 'age'  => 3],
];


$youngDogs = function ($animals, $age){
    return array_filter(
        $animals, 
        function($animals) use ($age){
            $arr = [];
            if($animals['type'] == 'dog' && $animals['age'] < $age)
            {
                $arr = [
                    'name' => $animals['name'],
                    'type' => $animals['type'],
                    'age' => $animals['age'],
                ];
            }
            return $arr;
        }
    );
};


var_dump($youngDogs($animals, 13));
```

Comment: Jeez, that is it! It worked, finally. Thank you very much!

Comment: 1. The variable `$age` is quite useless as a function argument since it will never be passed and will there for _always_ be the default. 2. The variable `$filter` (which the OP seem to want to use as `$age`) is never even used.

Comment: No problem, pidari.

Comment: How can I put it in use?

Comment: Change `function ($animals, $filter){` to `function ($animals, $age){`

Comment: @pidari Look at AbraCadaver's answer. It takes all the variables into account.

Comment: @OlegLubimoff That will still not pass `$age` to the `array_filter`-callback. Plus, the callback should return true or false. No need for the whole `$arr`-part.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Sorry, my bad, you need `function($animals) use ($age){` in inner function and `function ($animals, $age){` in outer.

Comment: I wish I could have given both @OlegLubimoff and Abra best answers!